# Magento 2 Dynamic text in order email based on products bought

Tags: magento2, order-email

I would like to display different text in the *order confirmation emails* depending on the items customer purchased . For example, when customer bought Gift Cards, when I'd like to show some extra text like terms & condition in the confirmation emails. What's the best approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

In the admin

> Marketing > Communications > Email Templates

Add new email template and load Order confirmation email and then you can add whatever you want.

Comment: But I want to show the extra text only when certain Items is bought. I don't think this can be done via Email Templates or am I mistaken?

Comment: Okay, then you can override this file: /app/design/frontend/custom/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml and put conditions based on you item.